# howto send a parameter when executing a android app with adb.exe shell command

Tags: java, android, adb

i start an android app with "adb.exe shell" as follow and this works fine:

```
shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -n mypackage/.myActivity
```

How can I provide a parameter to the command and how can I read it in my app ?

```
shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -n mypackage/.myActivity <PARAMETER>

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       String myParameter=getHowtoReadaParamter();
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From `am` help:

```
-e|--es <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE> ...
--ez <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_BOOLEAN_VALUE> ...
--ei <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE> ...
--el <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_LONG_VALUE> ...
--ef <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE> ...
--eu <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_URI_VALUE> ...
--ecn <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_COMPONENT_NAME_VALUE>
--eia <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_INT_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_INT_VALUE...]
--ela <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_LONG_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_LONG_VALUE...]
--efa <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE>[,<EXTRA_FLOAT_VALUE...]
```

So you can send a string parameter like this:

```
shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -n mypackage/.myActivity -e param value
```

and read it in activity:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("param")
```

Comment: what is value is something like this "Firstname Lastname"